# Perl Map Function not working as expected

Tags: arrays, perl, dictionary

I need some help with the map function in Perl, it seems to croupte my arrays.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Math::Trig;

my @Degre = map {rand(360)} (1..2000);
my @step= map {rand(.5)} (1..2000);
my @aa = map {rand(2000)} (1..2000);
my @bb = map {rand(2000)} (1..2000);

for ($i = 0; $i <=100; $i++)

{
my @xx = map {$aa[$_]*(cos($Degre[$_])*(pi/180))}(1..2000);
my @yy = map {$bb[$_]*(cos($Degre[$_])*(pi/180))}(1..2000);

@Degre = map {@Degre[$_] + @step[$_]} (1..2000);


print "@bb[1]  @aa[1]  @Degre[1] @step[1] \n";
}
```

Now the out put of this gives

```
1146.56471948439  1909.33326800968  329.443529905881 0.117635819122725
1146.56471948439  1909.33326800968  343.482356802257 0.117635819122725
1146.56471948439  1909.33326800968  164.500200570578 0.117635819122725
1146.56471948439  1909.33326800968  252.734665366625 0.117635819122725
1146.56471948439  1909.33326800968  274.983382178209 0.117635819122725
1146.56471948439  1909.33326800968  324.609187610893 0.117635819122725
1146.56471948439  1909.33326800968  261.96207333817 0.117635819122725
1146.56471948439  1909.33326800968  279.442105351764 0.117635819122725
```

With the 3rd column being the degrees, I don't see why it seems to jump around randomly when I expected it to increase in 0.117635..... steps?

Cheers

UPDATE

To confirm I am trying to get the map statment to do the following

```
for ($x = 0; $x <=2000; $x++)
{

$degre[$x] = $degre[$x] + $step[$i]
}
```

altering the code to

```
for ($i = 0; $i <=100; $i++)

{
my @xx = map {$aa[$_]*(cos($Degre[$_])*(pi/180))}(1..2000);
my @yy = map {$bb[$_]*(cos($Degre[$_])*(pi/180))}(1..2000);

#@Degre = map {$Degre[$_] + $step[$_]} (1..2000);
for ($x = 0; $x <=2000; $x++)

{
$Degre[$x] = $Degre[$x] + $step[$x];
}
```

gives the following out put

```
738.346205775827  646.171091419262  395.07480695473 0.484472140779317
738.346205775827  646.171091419262  395.559279095509 0.484472140779317
738.346205775827  646.171091419262  396.043751236288 0.484472140779317
738.346205775827  646.171091419262  396.528223377068 0.484472140779317
738.346205775827  646.171091419262  397.012695517847 0.484472140779317
738.346205775827  646.171091419262  397.497167658626 0.484472140779317
738.346205775827  646.171091419262  397.981639799406 0.484472140779317
738.346205775827  646.171091419262  398.466111940185 0.484472140779317
```

as you can see the degree column now incremented correctly by the step value each time thought the loop. So why does map not do the same.

Comment: one question does the line "@Degre = map {$Degre[$_] + $step[$_]} (1..2000);" over right the original array values? or add to the array?

Comment: Incidentally, `map {} (1..2000)` is an inefficient way of doing things, because it creates a 2000-element array populated with the numbers 1 to 2000.  A for loop that does the same thing would be more efficient: `$Degre[$_] += $step[$_] for (1..2000)`

Comment: When i tested a for loop (using the code in my question above). and bench marked it against using "map" it was signifently slower. I will try again with the code you suggest. Cheers :)

Comment: well interesting using the map function i get 574 cycles per second, the loop code you gave above 676, so nearly 20% improvement. Thank you for the tip sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `@Degre` gets changed inside the loop every time where as `aa` `bb` and `step` remains unchanged.

```
  print "$aa[1]  $bb[1]  $Degre[1] $step[1] \n";
```

The above shows correct value as calculated in

```
 @Degre = map {$Degre[$_] + $step[$_]} (1..2000);
```

Print `@xx` and `@yy` in your print statement instead of `@aa` and `@bb` and see the values change as per calculation.

Put a `@Degre=sort(@Degre);` just before the `for` loop and see the results. Below are the results after sorting-

```
1726.50146484375  681.5185546875  0.624771118164063 0.456436157226563 
1726.50146484375  681.5185546875  1.15629577636719 0.456436157226563 
1726.50146484375  681.5185546875  1.7493896484375 0.456436157226563 
1726.50146484375  681.5185546875  2.49296569824219 0.456436157226563 
1726.50146484375  681.5185546875  2.861083984375 0.456436157226563 
1726.50146484375  681.5185546875  3.20767211914063 0.456436157226563 
1726.50146484375  681.5185546875  3.44265747070313 0.456436157226563 
1726.50146484375  681.5185546875  11.8232574462891 0.456436157226563 
1726.50146484375  681.5185546875  12.2711944580078 0.456436157226563 
1726.50146484375  681.5185546875  12.3104858398438 0.456436157226563 
1726.50146484375  681.5185546875  13.2642059326172 0.456436157226563 
1726.50146484375  681.5185546875  13.4784698486328 0.456436157226563 
1726.50146484375  681.5185546875  103.224014282227 0.456436157226563 
1726.50146484375  681.5185546875  103.868133544922 0.456436157226563 
1726.50146484375  681.5185546875  104.103759765625 0.456436157226563 
1726.50146484375  681.5185546875  104.71240234375 0.456436157226563
```

As you can see, the calculation is correct i.e. in the first row `0.624771118164063 + 0.456436157226563` is `1.15629577636719` data in the second row and so on.

However, there is a jump from `3.44265747070313` to `11.8232574462891` at some point. I am not sure why that may be happening happening, but my assumption is that the indexing goes wrong at a certain point. This is resolved using code below

```
@Degre = map {$Degre[$_] + $step[$_]} (0..@step-1);
```

This time the output is much more consistent in the third column-

```
1139.18230471501  192.716943394942  183.715442551381 0.45937396317494 
1139.18230471501  192.716943394942  184.174816514556 0.45937396317494 
1139.18230471501  192.716943394942  184.634190477731 0.45937396317494 
1139.18230471501  192.716943394942  185.093564440906 0.45937396317494 
1139.18230471501  192.716943394942  185.552938404081 0.45937396317494 
1139.18230471501  192.716943394942  186.012312367256 0.45937396317494 
1139.18230471501  192.716943394942  186.471686330431 0.45937396317494 
1139.18230471501  192.716943394942  186.931060293605 0.45937396317494 
1139.18230471501  192.716943394942  187.39043425678 0.45937396317494 
1139.18230471501  192.716943394942  187.849808219955 0.45937396317494 
1139.18230471501  192.716943394942  188.30918218313 0.45937396317494
```

Comment: Oh and I was printing aa bb and step just for testing. I wanted to see that they remained constant.

Comment: Why would i need to sort? if $degre[1] = 10 and $step[1] = 5 then I would expect each for loop to incress $degre[1] by 5. So I don't see why sort function is needed.....

Comment: I said sort just to see the incremental increas of degre. No other purpose.

Comment: but why are they not already in order? i was expecting the map statement to be the equilivent of a for loop. the value in each element of array \@Degre would be incremented by the equlivent step value in the array \@step. see my update in the original question

Comment: No, they are not in order. You use `random` to populate the array using `map`. `RANDOM` will no necessarily fetch you values in sorted order. Map does what you think (the work of the `for` loop, per se), but will not `sort` the data unless you sort it. An the errors in your code, i think you used `use strict;` so in that case you need to declare all variables used before using it using `my`.

Comment: Also its pretty evident from the data i posted in my answer that the value in array `@degre` is exactly what its supposed to be according to the addition inside the `for` loop. The data is just not sorted which makes you think the values are jumping around.

Comment: If I had 2 arrays of 5 elements. the first one "3,8,1,3,7" (randome numbers) and the second "1,2,3,4,5" and passed it through a for loop of "for x = 1 to 5 {array1[x] = array1[x] + array2[x] \n print array1[1]}" this would give me and out put of "3,4,5,6,7" no need to sort. as each loop would increment the first value of array1 by the first value of array2. if you look at your out put it is still not incrementing "degre by the step value" step value is 0.45643.... the output goes from 0 - 104.

Comment: So `array1[1]` will be `10`. Remember you always print index `1` of the array. You are overwriting `@degre` every time and then in the next pass you are adding the existing values in `@degre` again with values in `@step`.

Comment: see my update. and the difference between using a for loop and using the map function.

Comment: I obtained almost a similar output using `map` in my answer. Your third column still shows an increasing value, which is similar to what I showed. Can't see anything unusual.

Comment: mine increases by the value in the step column. yours shows a random incress. Your output is not similar to mine. For it to be correct each value in the third column should equal the value above it + the value in the forth column which is static. "Similar is not the same as" in yours it jumps from 3 to 11 at one point and then up to 103

Comment: you may also want to check your maths. 0.624771118164063 + 0.456436157226563 is 1.0812.... not 1.15629....

Comment: ahh that's the one :) @Degre = map {$Degre[$_] + $step[$_]}0..#@Degre; it seems using map from 1 to 2000 puts things out of alignment, has to start at 0 as the array would, now I get the same out put as you :) Thank you sir.

Answer (score 3):

After adding

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

I got pretty different output:

```
Scalar value @Degre[$_] better written as $Degre[$_] at test3 line 20.
Scalar value @step[$_] better written as $step[$_] at test3 line 20.
Scalar value @bb[1] better written as $bb[1] at test3 line 23.
Scalar value @aa[1] better written as $aa[1] at test3 line 23.
Scalar value @Degre[1] better written as $Degre[1] at test3 line 23.
Scalar value @step[1] better written as $step[1] at test3 line 23.
Global symbol "$i" requires explicit package name at test3 line 14.
Global symbol "$i" requires explicit package name at test3 line 14.
Global symbol "$i" requires explicit package name at test3 line 14.
Execution of test3 aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Comment: cheers, I really must get in habit of using that! realy is no excuse not to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got @ where you mean $.

```
@Degre = map {@Degre[$_] + @step[$_]} (1..2000);
```

If you are trying to access elements of @Degre and @step then you want 
$Degre[$_] etc.

I'm not clear what @xx/yy are for either - they don't appear to be used

Comment: the xx and yy are point on an eclipse. aa and bb are the height and withe  of the eclipse. So currently they ddo nothing but what this code snipit is doing is generating 2000 eclipse's. and using the value of the degree's calculating the X,y coordinates. each cycle incressing the degree by a set amount and recalculating the points.